# A form in controller: how to organize the value of -1 by default

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping({"/create", "/create/"})
public String createGet(CorePhrasesCreateForm corePhrasesCreateForm) {

    return "semantics/phrases/core/create";
}

@PostMapping({"/create", "/create/"})
public String createPost(@Valid CorePhrasesCreateForm corePhrasesCreateForm,
                         BindingResult bindingResult,
                         RedirectAttributes atts) {

    corePhraseFormValidator.validate(corePhrasesCreateForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "semantics/phrases/core/create";
    }

    atts.addAttribute("message", "Core phrases created");

    String result = "";

    return "redirect:/general/message";
}
```

**Form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<a th:href="@{/admin/}">Admin</a>
<br>
<br>



<h1>Add core phrases to the database</h1>
<br>

<br>
<form method="POST" th:object="${corePhrasesCreateForm}">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Quotation cluster (" "):</td>
            <td><input
                    type="number"
                    name="quotationCluster"
                    th:value="${quotationCluster}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('quotationCluster')}" th:errors="*{quotationCluster}">quotationCluster</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quotation Exclamation cluster ("!")</td>
            <td><input
                    type="number"
                    name="quotationExclamationCluster"
                    th:value="${quotationExclamationCluster}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('quotationExclamationCluster')}" th:errors="*{quotationExclamationCluster}">
                quotationExclamationCluster
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phrases</td>
            <td><textarea rows="5" cols="60" name="value" placeholder="Key phrases" th:text="${value}"></textarea></td>
            <td class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('value')}" th:errors="*{value}">value</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <br>
    <br>


    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**The problem:**
Right now quotationCluster and quotationExclamationCluster by default send 0. That is it the two fields are left empty, the controller will get zeroes.

But 0 is a meaningful value. For example some DBMS may start their IDs from 0. So, 0 is a taboo.

[image]

By default I need -1.

How can I organize that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's "sending" 0.  From looking at the debug view, those look like primitives.  Primitive int and long are 0 by default.  Either change those to Integer/Long, or set them to -1 in CorePhrasesCreateFor.